# Should I install GRUB while upgrading Ubuntu from 10.04 to 12.04 on a VPS?

Tags: 12.04, 10.04, grub2, upgrade, vps

I just purchased a VPS running Ubuntu 10.04. During the installation, it asked if I would like to install GRUB. I actually don't know if I want to install GRUB or not. I'm afraid that I may mess something up with the provider.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What does your VPS hoster tell you about 12.04 support? And what kind of VPS is it? KVM, OpenVZ, etc. Can you run your own kernel? Is Grub installed and being used now? Most providers have a web based panel in which you can reinstall your VPS. If you just started using their service, you can try to see if you can reinstall it with another template. But really, this is a support question of your provider in the first place.

Comment: as far as i've seen, VPS providers just give you a web panel that you can simply choose which OS do you prefer to be on your system; you dont get involved in really installing it. may be you're doing something wrong.

Comment: I've gotten ssh into the system and upgraded it.